# Dynamic length of Listview of Edittext not saving input

Tags: android

I have  listview of edittext boxes. I also have a button to add a new row into the list, thus, the list length is dynamic.

However, when I entered text into the edittext and press the add-button, my input disappears. I think my input is not captured when I added a new row into the list. How can I save my input so when I change the amount of rows, my text remains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is fine, but you need to persist the edittext's data. Try adding textwatcher to each edittext and save the text for each edittext in a array or something

Answer (score 0):

A ListView recycles its row views anyway, so this would still be a problem without changing the list length.  Rows that scroll off the visible portion of the ListView would lose their contents.  To fix the problem, text entered into the EditText needs to be stored in the underlying data model, not just in the view.

You'll probably need to add a TextWatcher (with `addTextChangedListener()`) to each EditText.  When one of the TextWatcher callbacks is called, get the text from the EditText and save it into the data model.

To keep track of which data element to save to during the TextWatcher callback, you might use a technique similar to the one used with the RatingBar in [this CommonsWare sample](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf).

Comment: I suspect my implementation of the idea I have using Listview may not be suitable, from what you have suggested. 

perhaps you can enlighten me on a better method? I would like my application to achieve the same functionality as that of the edit contacts' "add phone number". It is able to add and remove rows from the view dynamically.

Comment: @Jeremy: No, a ListView seems like a perfectly natural way to do what you're doing.  The issue isn't the ListView itself, but rather the need to save the data in some place that's more persistent than the view.  If you're overriding at least the `getView()` method of Adapter (or of one of its subclasses), you can attach a TextWatcher to the EditText before returning from `getView()`.  When the user enters or changes the text in an EditText, you can use the TextWatcher to save the text somewhere.

Comment: I've having another problem with this as well. I understand your methodology, but right now I can't click to focus onto the EditText box. I used an arraylist of initial size 2 before attaching the adapter, but now I can't focus onto the text box when there are more than or less than two items in the listview. Strangely it works well when there are just two.